# Make a configuration field required in Dropwizard

Tags: java, configuration, jackson, dropwizard

In a `Configuration` class for Dropwizard, if my yml file is missing a field, Dropwizard does not log anything nor throws any errors/exceptions.

How can I make it throw an error and fail to start if the configuration file is missing a required configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You can put `required=true` in the `@JsonProperty` annotation on the parameter of the constructor (not on the field itself).

Example:

```
public class MyConfiguration extends Configuration {

    @NotNull
    private final String hostname;

    public MyConfiguration(
            @JsonProperty(value="hostname", required=true) String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }

    // Getters, etc

}
```

Comment: did adding the `@notnull` annotation is not worked? i think it will also through the error , if we try to pass null value or fields is missing in Yml file.

Comment: @AmitK unfortunately no, with just `@NotNull` it does not log or throw any error.